# Flutter Android plugin add ml model

Tags: flutter

I can add ml model in flutter app Android folders but i was not able to add one in flutter plugin that u was building the option was grey out
And when open in Android studio the native code is full of import errors
I'm using hybrid composition
Is there any way I can load my model in native

I tried adding Tensorflow model by open the plugin Android floder in Android studio but the option was grey out
Works with flutter project Android folder

Don't suggest flutter tflite packages